# GridView from URL in android

Tags: android

Hi
I am creating GridView from url in android,everything is working scrolling is not smooth.How can I solve the scrolling problem.
Here is my code.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testlayout);
    GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(45, 45));
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView
                .setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://www.example.com?id="+position));
        return imageView;
    }
    protected Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(0);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private Context mContext;
    private Integer[] mThumbIds;
}
```

}

Comment: Is this some sort of a question? if you share your code, it's awesome, but please make it a question, post your code as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I have asked the question its about the scrolling problem

Comment: what scrolling problem? You wrote that scrolling is smooth...

Comment: Sorry I have say scrolling is not smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading image code from a remote server on the UI thread. By doing so you are blocking the UI thread for the duration of the download... for each new item created in the grid. You must perform the downloads on a separate thread.